# Proper way to rotate UIImage with GPUImage

Tags: ios, rotation, uiimage, gpuimage

I want to rotate a large UIImage using GPUImage because it's so much faster than core graphics, at least on iOS devices.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
 GPUImagePicture *src = [GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
 GPUImageFilter *rotationFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
 [rotationFilter setInputRotation:gpuRotationMode atIndex:0];
 [src addTarget:rotationFilter];
 [src processImage]
 [rotationFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

The only problem is that I get a strip of white pixels on the end (the black strips are not part of the image):

[image: gpuimage orientation rotation]
<sub>(source: [kevinharringtonphoto.com](http://www.kevinharringtonphoto.com/photos/i-HNHM8dj/0/L/i-HNHM8dj-L.png))</sub>

How do I get rid of that white strip?

Note: I am using other filters on top of the rotation filter. Maybe there's an issue in conjunction with other filters.

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of the input image?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of one of the layers you're using. It's too small. Did you pass the image through an image optimizer software? That also causes that sort of issues.